# How to get Fingerprint value of audio file in iphone?

Tags: ios

If i record audio in noisy background and then compare recorded audio file with local saved audio file to check both are same song are not ?  In iPhone

How Shazam and Sound Hound app works to generate Fingerprint of recorded audio in iPhone?

can anyone explore knowledge on algorithm to generate Fingerprint from audio file in ios.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast (but possibly not very helpful) answer is: They probably do a Fourier Transform of the audio and compare. If you have never heard of Fourier before, you may want to find an API for it - the transform itself is not a programming problem, it's a math/signals problem.